# Making request using WebSockets in sails but not receiving response from the server

Tags: websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm starting with Websockets and I have a problem.
I have a sails.js application that uses sockets to update the client side.

On the client side it makes an API call using `socket.get("/api/v1/actor...")` to bring all the items of the database. When I see what the WebSocket's traffic on the Chrome console:

[image: Chrome console after doing an API call using socket.get]

As you can see, the connection has been established and the API call has been correctly done through the socket. 
The problem is, there is no answer from the server, not even an error.

If I make the same API call using ajax, I get response, but it doesn't work using WebSockets.
Any idea what might be producing this behavior?

**EDIT:** I add here the code [here](https://github.com/natgeo/activitystreams/blob/d374889d7743c9240e088c6275054010e36c7aa9/api/controllers/ActorController.js#L447) that processes the request and this one [here](https://github.com/natgeo/modules-activitystream/blob/0c9af366e27a50e5b71065322a6888b8bb97f2cb/app/scripts/modules/activityStream.coffee#L61) that sends the request, but the problem is that it never execute this code. I think we  we are closer to the find the cause, since we think it has to do with a network problem. We figured there is an F5 reverse-proxy which is not properly set up to handle websockets

Comment: Can you show the code that is responsible for sending back a response?

Comment: I just edited with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer didn't make any sense now that I've seen the code that's why I've edited it. I only answered because I could't comment on your question and ask you for the code.

Your calling code seems correct and the server side of things the process of response should be handled automatically by the framework, you only need to return some JSON in the controller method.

I instantiated a copy of the server (just changed the adapters to run it locally) and the server replied to the web socket requests (although I only tested the route '/index').

Normally when the problems are caused by a reverse proxy the socket simply refuses to connect and you can't even send data to server. Does the property "socket.socket.connected" returns true?

The best way to test is to write a small node application with socket.io client and test it in the same machine that the application server is running, then you can exclude network problems.

Comment: Hey, I just edited the question and added the code where I use `io.socket.get`, but I think there is a network problem. What happens is that the callback is never executed and the server doesn't seem to notice when I do a request using WebSockets.